# Date formatting in MySQL for filtering by AngularJS date filter

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, sorting

I'm using MySQL, AngularJS, and ngTable to build out my tabular data, and I'm having issues sorting.

Database

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`packageid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  // 2014-10-30 15:31:56
`status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
```

SQL

```
$query = $this->db->query( 
    "SELECT packageinstance.id, 
            packageinstance.created  // 2014-10-30 15:31:56
            DATE_FORMAT(packageinstance.created, '%b %e, %Y') as date, // Jan 1, 2014
            user.username, 
            status.name as status 
    FROM packageinstance 
    JOIN user   ON user.id   = packageinstance.creatorid 
    JOIN status ON status.id = packageinstance.status 
    WHERE    packageinstance.locationid = ? 
    ORDER BY packageinstance.created DESC", array( $locationId ) );
```

AngularJS within ng-repeat="doc in documents"

```
<td data-title="'Date'" 
    sortable="'created'" 
    ng-bind="(doc.created|date:mediumDate)"></td> // attempt one

<td data-title="'Date'" 
    sortable="'date'" 
    ng-bind="(doc.date|date:mediumDate)"></td> // attempt two
```

With either of these formats the sorting isn't working as it sorts based on a string.  Is there anyway to convert the date to something that Angular can filter, but sorts based on date value, that only requires changes in SQL statement?  If not what do I need to do to get the sort to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the MySQL docs I found another date function UNIX_TIMESTAMP, which I used to replace DATE_FORMAT in the query.

```
$query = $this->db->query( 
    "SELECT packageinstance.id, 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(packageinstance.created) as epoch_time, // replaced DATE_FORMAT
            user.username, 
            status.name as status 
    FROM packageinstance 
    JOIN user   ON user.id   = packageinstance.creatorid 
    JOIN status ON status.id = packageinstance.status 
    WHERE    packageinstance.locationid = ? 
    ORDER BY packageinstance.created DESC", array( $locationId ) );
```

This allowed the Angular's date filter to do it's job, but was displaying Jan 17, 1970 for all dates. A bit more work and I remembered that a timestamp is the amount of seconds since Jan 17, 1970 (epoch time), which needs to be multiplied by 1000 to arrive at the proper date prior to filtering so I added this to the Angular markup, and it now filters correctly for users, and sorts correctly using underlying timestamp.

```
<td data-title="'Date'" 
    sortable="'epoch_time'" 
    ng-bind="(doc.epoch_time*1000|date:mediumDate)"></td>
```